# How to move files between processes in Nextflow without copying the files

Tags: nextflow

I have a working sample that creates a file; then sends the file path to the next process. However, upon examination of the /work/xx files, *it appears the download process output is copied to the decompress work area*. While this will work, it will be very inefficient for files that are large ie, 60GB.

- How can I modify this to use some sort of shared area ?
- Also, these files were left in the work area after processing. How is cleanup supposed to work ? Keeping the process files like command.* is OK, but keeping hundreds of GB around after a run is not.

  ```
   process download {
   input:
      val zip
   output:
      path "./${zip}/${zip}.zip", emit: zipPath
   shell:
      """
      mkdir "./!{zip}"
      echo "foo" >  "./!{zip}/!{zip}.zip"
      echo "bar" >> "./!{zip}/!{zip}.zip"
      """
  ```

  }

  ```
  process decompress {
  input:
   path zipPath
  output:    
  shell:
   """
   echo !{zipPath}
   cat !{zipPath}
   """
  ```

  }

  ```
   workflow { 
   download("ZIP01")
   println download.out.zipPath
   decompress(download.out.zipPath)
  ```

  }

Answer (score 3):

Nextflow makes a symbolic link in the working directory of the second process, pointing to the output file of the first process. It doesn't copy over the entire file.